# C++ STL: Trouble with string iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm making a simple command line Hangman game.

```
void Hangman::printStatus()
{
    cout << "Lives remaining: " << livesRemaining << endl;
    cout << getFormattedAnswer() << endl;
}

string Hangman::getFormattedAnswer()
{
    return getFormattedAnswerFrom(correctAnswer.begin(), correctAnswer.end());
}

string Hangman::getFormattedAnswerFrom(string::const_iterator begin, string::const_iterator end)
{
    return begin == end? "" : displayChar(*begin) + getFormattedAnswerFrom(++begin, end);
}

char Hangman::displayChar(const char c)
{
    return c;
}
```

(Eventually, I'll change this so `displayChar()` displays a `-` or a character if the user has guessed it, but for simplicity now I'm just returning everything.)

When I build and run this from VS 2010, I get a popup box:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> xstring Line: 78
>
> Expression: string iterator not
>   dereferenceable

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try getting the backtrace while debugging, to be sure the code you posted causes this behaviour?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using a recursive implementation?  An iterative implementation would be simpler.

Comment: @James yeah, you're right. I implemented it iteratively and now it works.

Comment: Looks like an off-by-one type of issue when begin == end - 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the evaluation of:

```
displayChar(*begin) + getFormattedAnswerFrom(++begin, end)
```

In executing this statement, it is evident that your compiler is first incrementing `begin`, returning the "next" `begin` for use as the first argument to `getFormattedAnswerFrom`, and *then* dereferencing `begin` for the argument to `displayChar`.

When `begin` is one behind `end`, then `begin != end` so `displayChar(*begin) + getFormattedAnswerFrom(++begin, end)` will run. Your compiler increments `begin`, so now `begin == end`, and the dereference of `begin` is invalid.

See also: [Order of evaluation in C++ function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/order-of-evaluation-in-c-function-parameters/2934965#2934965)

Comment: Does the C++ spec define the order of evaluation of sub-expressions of binary operators or is it just common to go right-to-left, as your assert?

Comment: @David: It's UB, at least for primitive types. For user types it's unspecfied, but could be undefined, too (I don't know exactly).

Comment: @David, I don't think that the C++ standard specifies whether `*begin` or `++begin` will execute first. I didn't intend to assert right-to-left evaluation of subexpressions, so I have updated my answer.

Comment: In fact, I once worked at a company that used the Intel *and* Visual C++ compilers. The Intel compiler tended to evaluate left-to-right and the Visual C++ compiler tended to evaluate right-to-left. This led to a few issues where some test cases would succeed if compiled with `icc` but fail if compiled with `cl`.

Comment: I thought that plain order of operations went left-to-right?
In any case, this is yet another example of why ++x or x++ should be avoided if used as part of a greater expression.

Answer (score 0):

If `correctAnswer` is empty, `correctAnswer.begin()` will be the same as `correctAnswer.end()` and not be dereferenceable.

Comment: But shouldn't it immediately terminate the recursion then?

Comment: He has a check for that. Are you saying that even if begin == end, displayChar(*begin) + getFormattedAnswerFrom(++begin, end); will still be computed?

Comment: @jpalecek: Ah yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine to me. However, remember any heap or stack corruption could produce this error. You need to grab the stack trace and look inside correctAnswer, and ensure that both it and the instance of Hangman in question are valid objects.

Also, I'm just flat out a little concerned about your functions here. They seem very strange. Why not just replace with std::for_each?

Edit@comment:
If you have C++0x, you can just do

```
std::for_each(correctAnswer.begin(), correctAnswer.end(), [this](const char& ref) {
    std::cout << this->displayChar(ref);
});
```

Else, you will have to do something that looks a little like this:

```
struct helper {
    Hangman* ptr;
    void operator()(const char& ref) {
        std::cout << ptr->displayChar(ref);
    }
};
helper Helper;
Helper.ptr = this;
std::for_each(correctAnswer.begin(), correctAnswer.end(), Helper);
```

Comment: Edited in. You shouldn't have problems with that.

Comment: Intriguing. Can you explain the syntax of the top example? What's the significance of `[this]`?

Comment: When using lambda captures, [this] is a special dispensation where the this pointer is captured by value, and the resulting lambda is considered to be a member lambda, effectively.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293599.aspx#methodLambdaExpressions Strictly, I didn't have to dereference this inside the body, but did anyway.