# What is the order of evaluation for function arguments?

Tags: c++, parameters, language-lawyer, order-of-execution

If we have three functions (foo, bar, and baz) that are composed like so...

```
foo(bar(), baz())
```

Is there any guarantee by the C++ standard that bar will be evaluated before baz?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

No, there's no such guarantee. It's unspecified according to the C++ standard.

Bjarne Stroustrup also says it explicitly in "The C++ Programming Language" 3rd edition section 6.2.2, with some reasoning:

> Better code can be generated in the
>   absence of restrictions on expression
>   evaluation order

Although technically this refers to an earlier part of the same section which says that the order of evaluation of parts of an expression is also unspecified, i.e.

```
int x = f(2) + g(3);   // unspecified whether f() or g() is called first
```

Comment: Yes, but better code could be WRITTEN (=cleaner) if expression evaluation order was STRICT, which is generally a lot more important than code generation. See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612592/the-case-where-c-ab-is-not-equal-to-c-ab-b-b1?noredirect=1#comment74274141_43612592
So there, Stroustrup.

Comment: If ordering matters you are free to do the sequencing yourself. To do otherwise would always incur a cost for something that doesn't always (rarely?) matters. I think the policy of not paying for what you don't use is the only thing most C++ programmers agree on.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "unspecified behavior" instead of "undefined"?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Prior C++17, undefined behaviour if the functions causes side effects on the same memory location. Post C++17 it is unspecified.

Comment: It's not undefined, its implementation defined/unspecified.  That is, the code in the question can't cause abritrary unexpected behavior -- it *MUST* either run bar() then run baz() OR run baz() then run bar().  Nothing else is legal (it can't interleave the operations in the two functions if doing so would be visible).

Comment: @ChrisDodd downvoting an accepted answer due to using the word "undefined" vs. "unspecified" feels like malicious pedantry to me... I didn't say this is "undefined behavior", and otherwise "undefined" and "unspecified" seem synonymous? In any case, proposing an edit to the answer would have been a more productive way to discuss this

Comment: `string Config::value(string sKey, bool bReload)`. `void foo(Config::value("a", true), Config::value("b"), false);` Using 2 true would lost be wasteful, using 1 true doesn't guarantee the other one also come from a reloaded config.

Comment: Since left-to-right order _is_ guaranteed for _braced-init-lists_, `std::apply(foo, std::tuple{bar(), baz()})` would be save to use

Answer (score 28):

From [5.2.2] Function call,

> The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. All side effects of argument expression evaluations take effect before the function is entered.

Therefore, there is no guarantee that `bar()` will run before `baz()`, only that `bar()` and `baz()` will be called before `foo`.

Also note from [5] Expressions that:

> except where noted [e.g. special rules for `&&` and `||`], the order of evaluation of operands of individual operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the order in which side effects take place, is unspecified.

so even if you were asking whether `bar()` will run before `baz()` in `foo(bar() + baz())`, the order is still unspecified.

Comment: An example of a "special note" from [5.14] Logical AND operator: "Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`."

Answer (score 21):

There's no specified order for bar() and baz() - the only thing the Standard says is that they will both be evaluated before foo() is called. From the C++ Standard,  section 5.2.2/8:

> The order of evaluation of arguments
>   is unspecified.

Comment: The fact that they are evaluated before foo() is a bit reassuring, at least.

Comment: @BillKotsias The standard also says function calls cannot overlap (i.e. an implementation can't run line 1 of `bar`, then line 1 of `baz`, then line 2 of `bar`, etc.), which is also nice. :-)

Answer (score 17):

C++17 specifies evaluation order for operators that was unspecified until C++17. See the question [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/) But note your expression

```
foo(bar(), baz())
```

has still unspecified evaluation order.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, the relevant text can be found in [8.3.6 Default arguments/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.default#9) (Emphasis mine)

> Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called. **The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified**. Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in a default argument, even if they are not evaluated.

The same verbiage is used by C++14 standard as well, and is found under [the same section](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.fct.default#9).

Answer (score -1):

As others have already pointed out, the standard does not give any guidance on order of evaluation for this particular scenario. This order of evaluation is then left to the compiler, and the compiler might have a guarantee.

It's important to remember that the C++ standard is really a language to instruct a compiler on constructing assembly/machine code. The standard is only one part of the equation. Where the standard is ambiguous or is specifically implementation defined you should turn to the compiler and understand how it translates C++ instructions into true machine language.

So, if order of evaluation is a requirement, or at least important, and being cross-compiler compatible is not a requirement, investigate how your compiler will ultimately piece this together, your answer could ultimate lie there. Note that the compiler could change it's methodology in the future