# c++ arguments evaluation order

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order of evaluation in C++ function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/order-of-evaluation-in-c-function-parameters)

In C++
is the order of arguments evaluation defined or undefined?

My friend said it's defined , and like a STACK, been pushed from rightmost to left.
Is this right or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not defined by the C++ standard.