# C++ summation program

Tags: c++

I have created two functions and return the value to main part.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a =8;
int g(){a++; return a-1;}
int f(){a++; return a;}

int main (){
    cout << g()+f()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't why the output would be **18** but not **17**. I was wondering if anyone can explain this in detail for me? Thanks for your help

Comment: f:8+1; g:9+1-1; g+f:18; Do not remember which function will be call first, but result will be the sane in this case

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you expect (and why) and what do you get?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have got it right now

Comment: because in c++ the order of function parameter evaluations (is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2934909/847349). Try `g()+f()` and you get quite another answer.  It's just a bad idea to return and mutate a variable from the same function. What would you expect? Check out this too: http://herbsutter.com/2014/12/01/a-quick-poll-about-order-of-evaluation/

Comment: @May what have you gotten right now?

Comment: @Dmitry Ledentsov I understand the process and the reason why the program generate 18 but not 17. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov, Refrain from saying undefined for something that is unspecified. One has worse consequences.

Comment: I refer you to my first comment: please state clearly what you get, and what you expect. Your question is quite unclear as it stands.

Comment: @chris, indeed. Will take care about wording next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, note that the arguments to `operator +` are not sequenced, which means `g()` and `f()` can be evaluated in two orders, `g()` followed by `f()`, or `f()` followed by `g()`. It just happens that in this particular case, both of these orderings give a the same result, `18`, achieved in different ways:

- `g()` followed by `f()`: `g` increments `a` to `9`, and returns `8`. `f` increments `a` to `10` and returns `10`. The sum is `18`.
- `f()` followed by `g()`: `f` increments `a` to `9` and returns `9`. `g` increments `a` to `10` and returns `9`. The sum is `18`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Do you mean that if there is different order of functions, an entirely different result will be generated?

Comment: @May Well, here you get 18 regardless of the order. But in principle, yes, you can't rely on the ordering. It is even worse if you pass expressions that are not function calls. If you say something like `a++ + ++a` then you get *undefined behaviour*, which means your program is free to do whatever it likes.

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior. The two function calls can be evaluated by the compiler in any order.

From standard:
N3797, 1.9, paragraph 15

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators
>   and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. [
>   Note: In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the
>   execution of a program, unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced
>   evaluations of its subexpressions need not be performed consistently
>   in different evaluations. —end note ] The value computations of the
>   operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of
>   the result of the operator. If a side effect on a scalar object is
>   unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar
>   object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
>   object, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: It isn't *undefined behaviour*, but *unspecified*.

Comment: NO, you are wrong, the behavior is undefined. Maybe you wanted to say that the order of evaluation is unspecified.

Comment: No, YOU are wrong. It isn't undefined behaviour. AND the order of evaluation us unspecified.

Comment: I just added a quote from the standard

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't the quote that tells you what happens when the operands are the result of *function calls*.

Answer (score 0):

As variable 'a' is declared globally, its scope is throughout the program. In g(), a is incremented to 9  and a-1 is returned i.e., 8. The return statement doesn't affect the value of a. In f(), a is incremented to 10 and returned. Now, the print statement will be like this cout<<8+10; and prints 18 to the console.