# C++ execution order when passing function arguments

Tags: c++, function, expression, iso

A container class with the following interface:

```
template <typename T> class DynArray {
  /// Returns the number of elements in the array.
  inline size_t GetCount();
  /// Releases the internal memory from the \class DynArray
  /// and returns it. The memory must be deallocated manually.
  inline T* Release();
}
```

In a function call like

```
SomeFunction(arr.GetCount(), arr.Release())
```

I would have expected `arr.GetCount()` to be called before `arr.Release()`, but the reverse seems to actually happen causing the first parameter to be passed a value of `0` instead of the actual array size. I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Does the C++ standard say anything specific about order of execution when evaluating function parameters?

Comment: The standard does not mandate the order of execution when passed as params, this is left to the implementor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/order-of-evaluation-in-c-function-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says that the order is entirely unspecified.

The sequencing rules are far too complex to reproduce here, and it's hard to prove a negative, but a non-normative note conveniently summarises it for us:

> `[C++11: 5.2.2/4]:` When a function is called, each parameter (8.3.5) shall be initialized (8.5, 12.8, 12.1) with its corresponding argument. *[ Note:* Such initializations are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other (1.9) *— end note ]* *[..]*

(Identical text in C++14.)