# The case where c=a[b++] is NOT equal to c=a[b]; b=b+1;

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, post-increment, square-bracket

I almost pulled all of my hair. The code speaks for itself:

```
const float* const vertices = ...;
unsigned int j = 0;

        pair<float, float> poor;
        poor.first = vertices[j];
        poor.second = vertices[j + 1];
        CCLOG("WIT0 %f,%f", poor.first, poor.second);
        poor.first = vertices[j++];
        poor.second = vertices[j++];
        CCLOG("WIT1 %f,%f", poor.first, poor.second);

        j -= 2;

        poor = pair<float, float>(vertices[j], vertices[j + 1]);
        CCLOG("WIT2 %f,%f", poor.first, poor.second);
        poor = pair<float, float>(vertices[j++], vertices[j++]);
        CCLOG("WIT3 %f,%f", poor.first, poor.second);
```

The result is:

```
WIT0 -38.063835,32.743618
WIT1 -38.063835,32.743618
WIT2 -38.063835,32.743618
WIT3 32.743618,-38.063835 <- What about that, eh?
```

I always, always thought code is evaluated from left to right. Seems this isn't the case here.
Code run on Visual Studio 2015, Win32 Debug mode.

Can someone tell me if this is implementation specific and not addressed yet by the C++ guide?

Comment: Sure, but mine is better phrased

Comment: "I always, always thought code is evaluated from left to right." you thought wrong.

Comment: What is pretty confusing in this situation is that the "comma operator" *IS* a sequence point. But the comma in function call arguments *IS NOT* a sequence point.

Comment: Actually this is not exact duplicate, as it would have UB unrelated if ordere of evaluation of function arguments would be defined.

Comment: It's not just the order of evaluation, but [having two `j++` in the same expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior) is a big no-no.

Comment: Please make up your mind if it's duplicate or not, so I take according action. Thanks.

Comment: @BoPersson Oh, why is that? It's pretty clear to me.

Comment: It is not up to me, I did not vote for duplicate. But you have 2 issues - order of evaluation, and UB because you modify and read a variable without sequence point. (in this case you modify and read twice)

Comment: @Bill - Check the link. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson I did. THAT's not clear code.

Comment: @BillKotsias You cannot have 2 `j++` without a sequence point btw them. What is not clear to you? Even if you had one `j++` and use `j` in another - that is still UB.

Comment: @Slava The sequence point? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: @BillKotsias yes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point