# Can I read from a parameter at the same time as moving it into another parameter if a conversion is required?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Say I have code:

```
struct A {int val, string name};
A a{5, "Hello"};
fn(a.val, std::move(a));
```

Now it looks like I'm reading from `a` *and also* moving from `a` on the same line which looks bad as parameter ordering is generally undefined. However, as `std::move` is just a cast that should be ok - so I'm not actually reading from a `move`d from value.

What happens though if `fn` actually takes the second parameter by *value*:

```
fn(int first, A second);
```

In this case a new `A` must be constructed from the moved from value `a`. Would this start causing issues in my first example? I assume the constructor of the parameter `second` may be called before the first parameter `a.val` is read?

Comment: The [evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/order-of-evaluation-in-c-function-parameters)

Comment: Yes I understand. And I don't care if `std::move` or a.first is called first. I care if the implicit constructor for the parameter necessary in the second example is called first. I assume it is but its not clear.

Comment: You're right. Don't rely on this. You can cache the value of `a.val` and pass that to `fn` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are going to run into with this is [[expr.call]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.call)

> The postfix-expression is sequenced before each expression in the expression-list and any default argument. **The initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So, what could happen then is `second` is initialized first, which will be move constructed from `a` so it will steal its guts.  This means `a` is in a valid but indeterminate state when you go to initialize `first`.  Using `first` after that would be undefined behavior.  Now if the order is reversed you are fine but since the order is not specified you are not guaranteed any consistent behavior.

You are right that `std::move` isn't actually moving anything but initializing `second` with a object that was passed to `std::move` will cause `second` to use it's move constructor and that will actually move `a`.

Comment: Perfect, it was that *including every associated value computation and side effect* that I was looking for.