# Are delegated ctors affected by argument evaluation order?

Tags: c++

Up to [Order of evaluation in C++ function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/order-of-evaluation-in-c-function-parameters) and [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17) are delegate ctors affected by evaluation order?

```
struct A
{
    A( int a, int b ) : mA(a), mB(b) {}
    A( std::vector<u8>::const_iterator& aBuffer ) :
        A( CreateIntFromBuffer(aBuffer), CreateIntFromBuffer(aBuffer) ) {}
};
```

I need to repeat-my-self using `mA` and `mB` names another time?

There is some difference between the c++XX standards?

Comment: As for me then I have not understood what you are asking.

Comment: sorry buffer was passed as modifiable iterator.

Comment: The problem is the order on buffer (AB or BA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[class.base.init]**
>
> [7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init#7) The expression-list or braced-init-list in a mem-initializer is
>   used to initialize the designated subobject (or, in the case of a
>   delegating constructor, the complete class object) according to the
>   initialization rules of [dcl.init] for direct-initialization.
>
> **[dcl.init]**
>
> [19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#19) If the initializer is a parenthesized expression-list, the
>   expressions are evaluated in the order specified for function calls.

Given the above two paragraph, I would conclude that the order of evaluation in...

```
A( CreateIntFromBuffer(aBuffer), CreateIntFromBuffer(aBuffer) )
```

... of the two calls is unspecified (other than not interleaving). So you cannot rely on the left call completing before the right call, or vice-versa.

One could force a left to right evaluation order by using a brace init list like...

```
A{ CreateIntFromBuffer(aBuffer), CreateIntFromBuffer(aBuffer) }
```

... but I would call it at least a somewhat arcane use of brace initialization. Consider refactoring.

In a pinch, one could use a named function that returns an `A`, and delegate to the copy/move constructor:

```
struct A
{
    static A makeA(std::vector<u8>::const_iterator& aBuffer) {
        int a = CreateIntFromBuffer(aBuffer);
        int b = CreateIntFromBuffer(aBuffer);
        return A(a,b);
    }
    A( int a, int b ) : mA(a), mB(b) {}
    A( std::vector<u8>::const_iterator& aBuffer ) : A(makeA(aBuffer)) {}
};
```

Thanks to guaranteed copy elision, this won't actually involve any copies.

Comment: I dont like to repeat the member list (and types) another time...