# Why is the output of the folowing code 543 instead of 345?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int i, int j, int k) {
    printf("%d%d%d\n", i, j, k);
}

int main(void) {

    int x=1, y = 2, z = 3;

    f(x + y, y = x + z, z = x + y);

    return = 0;
}
```

Comment: The evaluation order for function arguments is not specified! In your case, it seems to be right to left, which would give the output you report. See here: [Order of evaluation in C++ function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/order-of-evaluation-in-c-function-parameters) - although this is for `C++` (but `C` has the same).

Comment: Moral of the story: write your code in such a way that the evaluation order is clearly defined.