# Do pointer arithmetic expressions count as instructions?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I have written a program that flips the elements of an array that are next to each other. for example

`1, 2, 1, 2` becomes `2, 1, 2, 1`

The code I wrote is:

```
#include <iostream>


template <class T>
void swap(T& a, T& b){
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
template <class T>
void oReverse(T* p, int size){
    for(T* e = p + size; p < e; p+=1){
        swap(*p, *p++);
    }

}
int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,2,1,2,1,2};
    oReverse(arr, 6);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `oReverse()` function takes care of the pointer magic.
The thing i couldn't understand is: Why does `swap(*p, *p++)` increment p by one.
At first I wrote p+=2 in the for loop, but it didn't work well, but it does with p++.
I thought the program would swap p and p++ then increment p by 2 then swap p and p++ again and again.

I hope i explained the problem clearly enough.

Comment: Is this supposed to compile? I ask because.. well.. it doesn't.

Comment: `p++` increments p by one.

Comment: `*p++` increments `p` (at some point before the next expression) and produces the original value of `*p`. Also, the evaluation order of arguments is unspecified and your code has undefined behaviour. (Don't try to be clever and do several things in one line.)

Comment: oups i left the (    std::cout << a << b << std::endl;)  i'll edit it out sorry.

Comment: That's not the reason this fails to compile. The unfinished `reverse` function opening is nesting everything past it. Frankly I don't see the need for that entire line.

Comment: I forgot that too... I think the program should be able to compile now.

Comment: `Do pointer arithmetic expressions count as instructions?` No. Pointer arithmetic expressions are constructs in the C++ language. Instructions are constructs of an assembly language and machine code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, `*p++` increments `p` *after* the value is fetched. So instead of

```
swap(*p, *p++);
```

you would like to do this:

```
swap(*p, *++p);
```

But this will not work either. The standard does not define in which order the arguments to a function should be evaluated. So instead of

```
swap(*p, *++p);
```

write

```
swap(*p, *(p+1));
p++;
```

and you'll be safe. Their behavior are not equivalent, because the evaluation order [is unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934917/6699433). But their *expected* behavior are equivalent.

With "expected behavior", I mean the behavior someone who does not know that the evaluations order is not defined by the standard typically would expect.

EDIT:

The evaluation order was unspecified before C++17, but from [C++17 it is specified from left to right.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38501596/6699433) But still, don't do things like that. "Clever" constructs have a tendency to cause problems.

Comment: Or skip the post-increment entirely and return to the original plan of using `p += 2` as the incrementor of the loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I agree. I just wanted to show how to translate the unsafe code to safe in a more general way.

Comment: You sure it's not implementation defined? `,` is a sequencing point. Actually it might be unspecified behaviour. I'll check.

Comment: @klutt: Except I think it's unspecified after all. I'll wait for someone to downvote or upvote my answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba It's unspecified. See link.

Comment: @Bathsheba Gave one to you too. You made me look it up and correct it. ;)

Comment: The evaluation order of arguments is now *specified* from C++17 (left to right).