# C++ Which called function in argument list runs first?

Tags: c++, stack

I tried 2 cases:

1. initialising `n1`, `n2` and parse to argument list of `calc()`

```
float n2 = get(nums), n1 = get(nums);
nums.push( calc( get(opr), n2, n1));
```

2. parsing two `get()` functions directly to the argument list

```
nums.push( calc( get(opr), get(nums), get(nums));
```

The function should calculate the result of `n1` and `n2`, where `n1` should be the older item in stack `nums`, while `n2` should be the top item.
But apparently Case 2 fails since `n1`, `n2` would be inverted, i.e., 7-4 results -3 instead of 3.

```
float get(stack<float> &stack) {
    float n = stack.top();
    stack.pop();
    return n;
}
```

```
float calc(char opr, float n2, float n1) {
    switch (opr) {
    case '+':
        return (n1 + n2);
        break;
    case '-':
        return (n1 - n2);
        break;
    case '*':
        return (n1 * n2);
        break;
    case '/':
        return (floor(n1 / n2));
        break;
    }
}
```

Why is this the case? My assumption is that the called functions in the argument list are not runned linearly from left to right. Or is there something else wrong?

Comment: The order arguments are evaluated in is not fixed or specified, it's up to the implementation (compiler) to select its own order. If you need a specific order for calls, do them before and store results in temporary variables.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605559/21105992

Comment: Also any of [several others](/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+order+function+arguments). Please search before posting.

Comment: Last thing you want is a side effect (or more) on the same line. Those are absolute magnets for bugs. Btw: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: *My assumption is that the called functions in the argument list are not runned linearly from left to right.*  Your assumption is incorrect.  The order that argument expressions are processed is an implementation detail.  Even with the same compiler, it could be left-to-right one call, and right-to-left the next call, and middle-out the third time.

Comment: Thanks all I was not aware of these posts before perhaps because the question title made it unclear.